# Looping through linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

So basically, what I'm trying to do is going through all the nodes and verify if `node.value is <= cost`. If it is I need to remove that node and in the end I want to store the nodes that weren't remove in a new struct. I'm not sure how exactly am I suppose to do this.

This struct can be an example:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    node * next;
}
```

I'm going through all the nodes and remove only the ones that doen't have the required.

```
node * verify_money(node * head, int cost)
{

    node * iterator = head;

    while(iterator != NULL){
       if(iterator.value <= cost) {  
           /*remove this node*/
       }
       iterator = iterator.next;
    }

return /*struct without nodes removed/*

}
```

I want to get the remaining nodes.

Comment: well, if you want to place the nodes that meet the `cost` requirement, make a new linked list and add these nodes to them, and then return the `new_list_head` of this new linked list.

Comment: Unless this is a homework assignment (or something similar) where you're required to write all the code yourself, you might want to use `std::list` or `std::forward_list` instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for really depends on your requirements, which you did not make clear enough.

If you are expected to modify the input list that is being verified, you can do something like this:

```
node * verify_money(node * head, int cost)
{
    node * iterator = head;
    node * previous = NULL;

    while (iterator) {
        node *next = iterator->next;

        if (iterator->value <= cost) {
            if (previous) previous->next = next;
            if (head == iterator) head = next;
            delete iterator;
        }
        else
            previous = iterator;

        iterator = next;
    }

    return head;
}
```

If you are expected to return a new list without modifying the original list, you can do something like this instead:

```
node * verify_money(node * head, int cost)
{
    node * new_head = NULL;
    node ** new_node = &new_head;

    node * iterator = head;
    while (iterator) {
        if (iterator->value > cost) {  
            *new_node = new node;
            (*new_node)->cost = value;
            (*new_node)->next = NULL;
            new_node = &((*new_node)->next);
        }
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }

    return new_head;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, Both cases are fine, I chose to return the head on the function argument, can you explain what you did in the If section?

Comment: @MickaelGonçalves a good way to learn how linked lists work is to sketch it out on paper, then step through the code instructions one at a time updating the drawing accordingly.